# What is the difference between "runtime version" and "version" in ractivejs?

Tags: ractivejs

When I use ractive, I saw some versions, but I don't know what is the difference between ractive.runtime.js version and ractive.js version.

So who can tell me?

Answer (score 1):

The runtime version doesn't include the template parser. That means your templates have to be precompiled in a build step. If in doubt, use the non-runtime version.